# Linux Shell - How to assign a variable to a binary expression?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have the following code:

```
TEMP1=$(awk '$12 == "beacon_server" {print}' < numbers2.log | awk -v var="$i" '{total += $var} EN    D {print total/NR}')
```

Almost the same for the other TEMP-variables.

Now i want to calculate the following and save it in a new variable RESULT:

```
RESULT=$(expr 100 - $TEMP1 - $TEMP2 - $TEMP3 - $TEMP4)
```

The error message is telling me that there is a non-integer argument  --> 
**expr: non-integer argument**

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Well, what are the values of each of the `TEMP` variables when you get that error? One or more of them *isn't* an integer. As an aside, prefer `RESULT=$(( 100 - $TEMP1 - $TEMP2 - $TEMP3 - $TEMP4))` to using the external command `expr`.

Comment: What do you mean by "binary expression" in this context?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I mean the multiple subtractions with binary expression (maybe it should be called binary expressionS)

Comment: @chepner: The TEMP variables are real numbers. If I do it without the expr as you said, I get this: `arithmetic expression: expecting EOF: " 100 - 1 - 2.23333 - 0.333333 - 0"`

Comment: @ErebosM, what binary expressions? `-` is not a binary expression, in the "bitwise" sense of the word (indeed, bitwise math doesn't generally make much sense with floating-point math).

Comment: @ErebosM, ...and inasmuch as you're trying to do non-integer math, the flagged duplicates are entirely apropos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message means that one of the arguments is not an integer to find which and to fix the problem you have to display variables content as the file numbers2.log is not provided we can't find the values.

echo variable

```
echo "TEMP1=$TEMP1"
...
```

Or

```
declare -p ${!TEMP*}
```

To compute floating point numbers values

```
exit | awk "END{ print 100 - $TEMP1 - $TEMP2 - $TEMP3 - $TEMP4 }"
```

or

```
bc -l <<<"100 - $TEMP1 - $TEMP2 - $TEMP3 - $TEMP4"
```

Comment: The problem is not indirect expansion, but using floating point numbers with `expr` (notice the `print total/NR` in the awk command).

Comment: How would this result in a problem? Or moreover how can I solve it with still using floating points?

Comment: `expr` command is limited can only compute integers

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul : The one with `exit` worked for me. Can you please tell me why you pipe `exit` into the `awk` function? What does the whole line do?

Comment: `exit | ` is to close input redirection for awk `awk '...' < /dev/null` works also

Comment: Why not just use `</dev/null` instead? Less overhead than setting up a pipeline.

Comment: Initially I was using `<&-` but it's not working with my current version of bash (4.2) whereas following man bash should close the the input, I remembered the `exit|` semantic which I already seen before, comparing `strace -f bash -c 'command'` there's an overhead